# RHPAM + KEYCLOAK/RHSSO -> Login failed: Not Authorized

Tags: keycloak

So I'm integrating RHSSO (based on keycloack) with RH Business Central (RHPAM) as authoring instance and no matter what I do after it redirects from the RH-SSO login page to the target/landing page of the RHPAM/BusinessCentral I always get the Login failed: Not Authorized

I have already followed the steps detailed here but still no-go; has anyone come across this before?

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6859451

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StUHT.png)

Comment: More details are needed to investigate your problem. Do you have any log files or stack traces with error messages? *Not authorized* indicates that credentials are not accepted or not available. Linking to a member-only solution is also not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if it come to page with error unauthorized message usually there are role mapping issues, please double check if user indeed has roles that needed for login to rhpam central.